# this inspection detects names that should resolve

Tags: python-3.x, pycharm

Делают сайт на Джанго, проимпортировал библиотеку через pip. Запустить сервер получается, но в PyCharm подчеркивает строки с django и вылазит ошибка this inspection detects names that should resolve, подскажите как с ней бороться